# Modificar salida sql con python

Tags: python, mysql

Al hacer una consulta de una determinada línea de una base de datos (MySQl) con python, la salida que me ofrece es del tipo :

```
Db_Host = '****'     
Db_Urs = '****' 
Db_Pass = '****' 
Db_Name = '****' 

def run_query(query=''): 
    datos = [Db_Host, Db_Urs, Db_Pass, Db_Name] 

    conexion = MySQLdb.connect(*datos)  
    cursor = conn.cursor()          
    cursor.execute(query)           

    if query.upper().startswith('SELECT'): 
        data = cursor.fetchall()   
    else: 
        conexion.commit()              
        data = None 

    cursor.close()                  
    connexion.close()                    
    return data


x = run_query(query='SELECT dni FROM empleados limit 1')
print x
```

Con esta salida:

```
((' 75849332D ',),)
```

Necesitaría saber si esa salida (probablemente tupla), puede convertirse en cadena para poder modificarla aparte posteriormente, es decir, que quede como una cadena normal:

```
75849332D
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido, @Cav. Cuando hagas una pregunta, intenta poner la información necesaria para que se pueda reproducir tu problema y así podamos ayudarte ([Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) en el Centro de Ayuda). Lo que indicas parece ser una tupla, pero falta información para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Sí, es cierto que parece una tupla, pero es como me da la salida y tal cual la he añadido. La base de datos es por MySQL, son varias columnas, entre ellas las que indico en la consulta, y la consulta a esta base de datos es la que indico arriba, solo pidiendo un registro.

Comment: Pues algo te has dejado de contar. No sabemos qué es `run_query` y por tanto no podemos reproducir tu ejemplo para ver qué le pasa. La salida tiene pintas de ser una tupla dentro de otra tupla, pero es casi seguro que la última coma sobra. Además, deberías indicar la etiqueta [tag:mysql] para saber la base de datos que estás trabajando.

Comment: Ok, lo edito. Además llevas razón, la última coma sobra...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si sabes que esa query siempre va a devolver eso (tupla dentro de tupla) puedes acceder al *string* interno usando indexación:

dentro de la función, en la última línea, puedes hacer:

`return data[0][0]`

O fuera de la función, cuando la llamas, puedes almacenar en `x`, directamente el *string* haciendo:

`x = run_query(query='SELECT dni FROM empleados limit 1')[0][0]`

o, en el print, puedes hacer:

`print(x[0][0])`

Lo suyo sería hacerlo en la función para que la misma función maneje posibles errores. Una posibilidad podría ser:

```
def run_query(query=''): 
    try:
        datos = [Db_Host, Db_Urs, Db_Pass, Db_Name] 

        conexion = MySQLdb.connect(*datos)  
        cursor = conn.cursor()          
        cursor.execute(query)           

        if query.upper().startswith('SELECT'): 
            data = cursor.fetchall()   
        else: 
            conexion.commit()              
            data = None 

        cursor.close()                  
        connexion.close()                    
        return data[0][0]
    except:
        return ("No ha sido posible realizar la conexión o ha habido "
                "un problema con la extracción y/o formateo de los datos")
```

Answer (score 2):

La salida que muestras es una monotupla dentro de otra monotupla. En resumidas cuentas, la cadena que buscas se obtiene mediante una doble indirección:

```
s = x[0][0]
```

Pero es mejor que visualices por un momento cuál era el resultado esperado de la consulta. Debe ser una secuencia de registros siendo cada registro una relación de los campos que tiene. Al hacer la consulta sólo por un campo, `dni`, sale una monotupla por registro devuelto, y sólo un registro porque no tendrás nada más almacenado en la tabla.

Pero podría haber devuelto más de un registro o, tal vez, ninguno. Es conveniente que tu programa no asuma a priori cuántos registros, por lo que es muy común acceder a los resultados con un bucle:

```
res = run_query(query='SELECT dni FROM empleados limit 1')

for row in res:
    print row[0]
```

O también

```
for (dni,) in res:
    print dni
```